# How to keep all elements on an HTML page in the same location when window is re-sized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The image should be in the box to the left on even when the window is re-sized
I've tried to set the position for the image to relative but that does not completely fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: can you show your html, javascript and css?

Comment: put your code here , or update it in jsfiddle

Comment: too many characters

Comment: #sidebar {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}

Comment: #sidebar h3 {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    color: #313131;
}

Comment: #sidebar ul {
    padding: 10px 0 25px 30px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #23318F;
}

Comment: #sidebar ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

Comment: <div id="sidebar">
                <h3>Titles</h3>
                    <div id="coverBar"> 
                        <img src="images/bbc.png" width="82" height="115" style="left:0px;"> 
                        <img src="images/british.jpg" width="82" height="115" style="left:88px;"> 
                       
                    </div>
            </div>

Comment: JavaScript is check monitor function, to check to see if the user entered a valid name an d password, a registration process that simply sends a POST request to a server then manipulates CSS and scrolls the images

Comment: you can put your HTML in the Question content , it will be easy to check your problems